# How to cluster and classify word-vectors

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, word2vec

i am currently training a skip-gram model to learn different objects by their description. After i got my word embeddings from  that model i want to cluster these in similar groups and label them.

My idea was to reuse the same model with the same embedding layer and let it learn categroies from their descriptions.

this is my current result:

[image: https://imgur.com/6xBQ6ng]

The the problem is that the new categories are labeled 60, 61 and 62.
The model interprets them as similar and puts them in the same space.

These categories shouldn't be the same and they are not near the vectors they should be.
Am i doing this wrong? How can i reuse my model to cluster and classifiy these objects?

```py
pretrained_vectors_cat =
array([[-0.00703605, -0.00456019, -0.07583138, ..., -0.00803135,
        -0.03794867, -0.03410311],
       [-0.06226502, -0.03059928, -0.07528683, ...,  0.11714505,
         0.01752528, -0.00584977],
       [-0.07654897, -0.04235281, -0.02850686, ...,  0.06900358,
         0.00327334, -0.10425693],
       ...,
       [-0.50258852, -0.57102433, -0.28687169, ..., -0.26322143,
        -0.0910767 ,  0.13004072],
       [-0.53029969,  0.71982554, -0.80099767, ...,  0.75670917,
        -0.61081131,  0.59293241],
       [ 0.22630654, -0.69713363, -0.1661163 , ..., -0.23165715,
         0.18017072, -0.90354915]])

with graph_pretrained.as_default():

    with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
        train_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size], name="train_inputs")
        train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1], name="train_labels")

    with tf.device(device_name):
        with tf.name_scope('embeddings_pretrained'):
            embeddings = tf.get_variable("embeddings", initializer=pretrained_vectors_cat)
            embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_inputs)

            embeddings = tf.cast(embeddings, tf.float32)
            embed = tf.cast(embed, tf.float32)

        with tf.name_scope('weights'):
            nce_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[vocabulary_size_cat, embedding_size],
                                                          stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)), 
                                      name="weight_matrix")

        with tf.name_scope('biases'):
            nce_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size_cat]), name="bias_matrix")

    with tf.name_scope('loss'): 
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.nce_loss(
                weights=nce_weights,
                biases=nce_biases,
                inputs=embed,
                labels=train_labels,
                num_sampled=num_sampled,
                num_classes=vocabulary_size_cat))

    loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

    with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learningrate).minimize(loss)

    norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keepdims=True))
    normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm

    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session(graph=graph_pretrained, config=session_config) as session:
    # Open a writer to write summaries.
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir + "/", session.graph)
    writer_loss = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir + "/loss {}".format(model_name))
    init.run()
    average_loss = 0

    for step in xrange(num_steps):      
        progbar.update(step)

        batch_inputs, batch_labels = generateCenterContextBatch(batch_size, window_size, new_project_mark)

        feed_dict = {train_inputs: batch_inputs, train_labels: batch_labels}#, embedding_placeholder: pretrained_vectors}

        run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
        _, summary, loss_val = session.run([optimizer, merged, loss],
                                            feed_dict=feed_dict,
                                            run_metadata=run_metadata)

        average_loss += loss_val

        # Add returned summaries to writer in each step.
        writer_loss.add_summary(summary, step)

        # Add metadata to visualize the graph for the last run.
        if step == (num_steps - 1):
            writer_loss.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step%d' % step)

    final_embeddings_category = normalized_embeddings.eval()

    # Save the model for checkpoints.
    saver.save(session, os.path.join(logdir_model", 'model.ckpt'))

writer_loss.close()
```

Comment: Try and shorten your code to make a minimal working example that reproduces your error, including input arrays, such that others can run your code and assist you.

Comment: **Why** do you want to "cluster these in similar groups and label them"? (Most uses of word-vecs don't require such a step.) It's also unclear what you mean by "reuse the same model with the same embedding layer & let it learn categories from their descriptions". Is this process shown in your code? (A word2vec vector-set, or even trained neural-net, can't necessarily turn "descriptions" into new categories or category-vectors, at least not without other assumptions.) And, how do you know results for "60, 61, & 62" aren't correct & where they "should" be? (What's your data & standard-of-truth?)

Comment: @gojomo, the results 60, 61, etc. are pseudonymized and each represent a technology. For better understanding why the neural net put these vectors for each technology where they are, i want to group similar ones and label them.

For example:
I want to cluster and classify these vecotors as "Cloud" (61)
8 := "Software as a Service"
28 := "Platform as a Service"
48 := "Infrastructure as a Service"

Comment: So i "reuse" the model by reusing the model architecture and initialising the embedding layer with the pretrained vectors. But after each training with different training data, the model groups these new vectors on the same place like "60, 61, 62"

Comment: Your intended result, & what standard process you might be trying to match, is still very unclear. It's not a usual word2vec process to "reuse the model architecture & intialise the embedding layer with pretrained vectors" to then do "each training with different training data" to have the model "group these new vectors in some desirable place". It would be recognizable to just train a word2vec model once with as much data as you can get, then cluster those results. Your other steps, of unclear motivation, & pseudonymized results which can't clearly demo the failure-mode make it hard to help.

Comment: Probably because the training data for them is different? Anyway, you have an embedding problem, not a clustering problem.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse thank you for your suggestion. 
The problem lies in the TensorBoard Projector. The cosine distances are calculated incorrectly, over sklearn I get the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

The TensorBoard Projector calculates the cosine distances wrong.
Getting the distances via sklearn results in the correct clusters.

TensorBoard might reduce the original dimensionality from 300 to 200 and computes the distances from the reduced dimensions. So the label "nearest points in the original space" is misleading.

--- check: installed_packages 
INFO: installed: tensorboard==1.13.1
INFO: installed: tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
INFO: installed: tensorflow==1.14.0